# Scraping Product Links at Coles.com.au 429 error with 1 request

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to webscraping and would like to scrape the links from the site below using scrapy:

https://shop.coles.com.au/a/national/everything/search/bread?pageNumber=1

I created the below xpath to scrape the links and when I test it out by going to inspect and pressing ctrl + f I get 51 matches which is equal to the number of products and so seems to be correct:

```
//span[@class="product-name"]/../../@href
```

However when I go into scrapy shell with the link and apply the command:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="product-name"]/../../@href').extract()
```

with or without a User agent I just get an empty list.

When I run the shell I get a 429 error, which indicates I have made too many requests. But as far as I am aware I have only made 1 request.

In addition I have also set up a spider for this where I set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1 and also get a 429 error.

Does anyone know why my xpath doesn't work on this site?

Thanks

Edit

Below is the spider code:

```
import scrapy


class ColesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coles'
    allowed_domains = ['shop.coles.com.au']
    start_urls = ['https://shop.coles.com.au/a/national/everything/search/bread/']

    def parse(self, response):
        prod_urls = response.xpath('//span[@class="product-name"]/../../@href').extract()
        
        for prod_url in prod_urls:
            yield{"Product_URL": prod_url}
```

Comment: Executable and simple code are better for your question.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I have provided the spider part of my code

Comment: The issue is not with too many requests. It seems that this website uses some mechanism to identify scrapers. You're getting 429 when trying to research it using requests.get, and even (once) when you try to read it from an incognito browser.

Comment: Is there a way of discovering how it is finding its a bot and working around it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a quick look around the website and it seems like the website is invoking a cookie challenges as well as requiring your IP address.

I think it may be worth thinking about trying scrapy-splash to render the page and go through the JS cookie challenges if you're hard on using scrapy.

Strangely I managed to get a 200 status code with headers,params and cookies with the requests package but couldn't get scrapy with same headers and cookies to recreate that response.

Comment: Thanks AaronS, I guess I'll have to work out how to use that one then.

Comment: Here's a couple of links 
https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rofkkuSf9iA

Comment: @ChristopherEll hey brother, I am working on the same website, you got any solution till now.